# How to redirect a specific search result using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

When searching for "interesting people" the search results page of my website is `https://example.com/?s=interesting+people&submit.x=0&submit.y=0`

Instead of displaying that search results page I would like this specific search result to 302 redirect using `.htaccess` to an existing page `https://example.com/interestingpeople`

For all other search results, I'd like the default search results page. So, for example, searching for "funny people" should still return and display the URL of `https://example.com/?s=funny+people&submit.x=0&submit.y=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to require is a straight forward redirect. However, in order to match against the *query string* portion of the URL, you need to use mod_rewrite with a *condition* that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =s=interesting+people&submit.x=0&submit.y=0
RewriteRule ^$ /interestingpeople [QSD,R,L]
```

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* makes it into an *exact match* string comparison (not a regex).

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` matches against an *empty* URL-path, ie. the document root.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4) is required to remove the *query string* from the redirected URL.

Comment: Thank you, MrWhite. This solution has worked perfectly.